# Regex to eliminate all hashtags except one

Tags: python, regex

For example I want to protect the hashtag `#hello`.

Inputs:

`#hello#need#help` , `#I#am#not#hello#regex#expert`

In both cases the output must be `#hello`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative look-ahead:

```
re.sub('#(?!hello)[a-zA-Z]+', '', string)
```